# Convert an array into object array with ids in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have the following array

```
["Design", "Survey", "Geotech", "Community", "Progress", "Planning", "Commercial", "Logistics", "Milestones", "Environment", "Quality", "Safety"]
```

and I would like to convert into it the following format, would be nice if the ids were random or unique

```
data = [
    {id: 1, title: 'Design'},
    {id: 2, title: 'Survey'},
    {id: 3, title: 'Geotech'},
    {id: 4, title: 'Community'},
  ];
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can access the index of the array element in the `map` callback function via the second parameter, so minimally it could be (if you don't care about whether id starts from 0 or 1):

```js
var arr = ["Design", "Survey", "Geotech", "Community", "Progress", "Planning", "Commercial", "Logistics", "Milestones", "Environment", "Quality", "Safety"];

console.log(
  arr.map((title, id) => ({id, title}))
);
```

---

If starts from `1`:

```js
var arr = ["Design", "Survey", "Geotech", "Community", "Progress", "Planning", "Commercial", "Logistics", "Milestones", "Environment", "Quality", "Safety"];

console.log(
  arr.map((title, id) => ({id: id+1, title}))
);
```

Comment: `id + 1` in the map function since OP wants 1-based id's.

Comment: also its not so understandable that how it works , at least for me

Comment: @DocMax Since OP states that the `id` could be random, I guess it doesn't matter as much. But good point.

Comment: Thanks this is perfect

Answer (score 3):

You can use [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) for that:

```js
var array = ["Design", "Survey", "Geotech", "Community", "Progress", "Planning", "Commercial", "Logistics", "Milestones", "Environment", "Quality", "Safety"];

var id = 1;
var data = array.map(function(x) {
  return {
    id: id++,
    title: x
  };
});

console.log(data);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
   var oldarr = [
   "Design", "Survey", "Geotech", "Community", "Progress", 
   "Planning", "Commercial", "Logistics", "Milestones", "Environment", 
   "Quality", "Safety"];

   var newArr = oldArr.map(function (element,index) {
     return { id : index + 1, title:element};
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

To generate Unique ID's, you can use this function from @broofa ([taken from this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/105034/create-guid-uuid-in-javascript)) which uses [*window.crypto*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/crypto), then use it in the map method:

```js
function uuidv4() {
    return ([1e7]+-1e3+-4e3+-8e3+-1e11).replace(/[018]/g, c => 
        (c ^ crypto.getRandomValues(new Uint8Array(1))[0] & 15 >> c / 4).toString(16)
    )
}

var data = ["Design", "Survey", "Geotech", "Community"];

var newArray = data.map(title => ({id: uuidv4(), title}));

console.log(newArray)
```

Note that the above uses a number of recent features, so not particularly compatible with older browsers.

Answer (score 0):

how about reduce

```
["Design", "Survey", "Geotech", "Community", "Progress", "Planning", "Commercial", "Logistics", "Milestones", "Environment", "Quality", "Safety"].reduce((accum , curr, indx) => accum.concat({id: indx+1, title: curr}), []);
```